# how to responsive image on a "height" basis in css display flex?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm not good at English, but I'll ask you a question!

I'm studying `flex` and having a problem :((

I used `flex-basis` to activate it according to the ratio.
but the image also shrink to fit the width(flex-basis)...:(
if to release the image width(100%), flex ratio was broken.

I'd like to make the image height fixed. shrink like `flex-basis`

how to responsive image on a `height` basis in css `display flex`?

I thought you might not understand the question.
I've attached a site and an image link for you!

```js
$(function(){
  $(".c_pro_list li").each(function(e){
    $(this).hover(function(e){
      $(this).siblings().removeClass("c_on");
      $(this).addClass("c_on");
    }, function(e){
      $(this).siblings().removeClass("c_on");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.c_pro_list > li {position: relative; padding:0 15px;}

.c_pro_info {position:absolute; bottom:1em; text-indent:1em;}
.c_pro_color li {float:left;}

li[class^="c_pro_list"] {overflow: hidden; display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-basis: 25%;}
div img {height: auto;}
li[class^="c_pro_list"] .c_pro_con {flex: auto;}

li[class^="c_pro_list"].c_on {flex-basis: 50%;}
```

```html
    <ul class="c_pro_list c_disf">
      <li class="c_pro_list1 c_on">
        <div class="c_pro_con">
          <a href="">
            <img src="/img/pro-1.png" alt="제품이미지1">
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="c_pro_list2"></li>
      <li class="c_pro_list3"></li>
</ul>
```

**image link**

> [https://cuveloper.github.io/flexTest/img/스택질문.PNG](https://cuveloper.github.io/flexTest/img/%EC%8A%A4%ED%83%9D%EC%A7%88%EB%AC%B8.PNG)

**A similar site is here. but This site dont used flex**

> http://www.justfog.com/renew_2019/

**Here is my test Link...**

> https://cuveloper.github.io/flexTest/index.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I hope that is the good solution for you

```js
$('.photo').on('click', function(e){
  if(!$(e.target).hasClass('active')) {
    $('.photo').removeClass('active')
    $(e.target).addClass('active')
  }
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
.photo {
  height: 200px;
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  border: solid 3px #ffffff;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  transition: flex-basis 0.3s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.photo.active {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="photo active" style="background-image: url(https://img-ik.cars.co.za/images/2017/8/Teslamodel3/tr:n-news_large/presskit-model-3.jpg);" ></div>
  <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(https://cnet4.cbsistatic.com/img/L2R9i7W2t6VkeKweGEMnERNpq_A=/2019/06/28/f7acb1bd-fa51-4063-b7c8-c79deb124684/tesla-model-s-promo.jpg);" ></div>
  <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(https://img-ik.cars.co.za/images/2017/8/Teslamodel3/tr:n-news_large/presskit-model-3.jpg);" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll use the background instead of the image! I'll try and come back! thank u

Comment: This approach is really very convenient. Pls, check my answer ;)